# Two users, two different .aspx pages loaded - can't figure out why

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, aspx

I have an .aspx page from the /SitePages library that loads different versions for each user. The rendered code and size of the .aspx pages are different from what I can see in the Chrome Dev Tools. I know that I have made changes to that page in SP Designer but it says that the file is checked in.
I also deleted all browser cache's on both user's machines and logged out and back in. I can't figure why this is happening. Any ideas?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Is this a publishing site? Are the files checked in and published? (As you said "SitePages", I'm guessing it's not, but just checking...)

Comment: Is all of the linked content checked in? Images, master pages, linked content to Content Editor Web Parts?

Comment: How are the users getting to the page? Are they following a link from somewhere else in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first guess you are looking at a versioning issue. If the site is a publishing site and the page was not "Published" eg a major version. This would explain the issue. Of course the two users would have to have different permissions. eg 1 can only read the other can edit. Page libraries have a setting under version control which determines who can see drafts. Change this and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the missing piece. A display template .html file was not published that a content editor webpart one that page was using. Therefore, only my site collection admin was able to see those changes already but a regular user was not. All good now. Thanks for your input.